# Scipy sparse matrix slicing returns IndexError

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, slice, sparse-matrix

If I try to slice a sparse matrix or see the value at a given `[row,colum]`, I get a `IndexError`

More precisely, I have the following `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` which I load from a file after saving it

```py
...
>>> A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((vals, (rows, cols)), shape=(output_dim, input_dim))
>>> np.save(open('test_matrix.dat', 'wb'), A)
...
>>> A = np.load('test_matrix.dat', allow_pickle=True)
>>> A
array(<831232x798208 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 109886100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
      dtype=object)
```

However, when I try to get the value at a given [row,column] pair, I get the following error

```py
>>> A[1,1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Why is that happening?

Just to clarify, I'm sure that the matrix is not empty, as I can see its content if I do

```py
>>> print(A)
  (0, 1)    0.24914551
  (0, 2)    0.6669922
  (1, 1)    0.75097656
  (1, 3)    0.6640625
  (2, 3)    0.3359375
  (2, 514)  0.34960938
...
```

Comment: look carefully at the `A` you show.  What is it?  type, shape, dtyope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save and reload your sparse array you have created an array with one entry; an object, being your sparse array. So A has nothing at [1,1]. You should use [`scipy.sparse.save_npz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html) instead.

For example:

```
import scipy.sparse as sps
import numpy as np

A = sps.csr_matrix((10,10))
A
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
np.save('test_matrix.dat', A)
B = np.load('test_matrix.dat.npy', allow_pickle=True)
B
array(<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
B[1,1]
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-969f8bd5206a> in <module>
----> 1 B[1,1]

IndexError: too many indices for array
sps.save_npz('sparse_dat')
C = sps.load_npz('sparse_dat.npz')
C
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
C[1,1]
0.0
```

Mind you you can still retrieve `A` from `B` like so:

```
D = B.tolist()
D
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
D[1,1]
0.0
```

Comment: `B.item()` can also be used to extract the single item from the array.